# Can't install pip on ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new on Stackoverflow and in programmation..

I must install pip, but I have one error that I can't solve.

I searched on other forums and here but I don't find anything.
I am on Ubuntu 14.02 and python 2.7.6

Here the error when I type `!pip install yapf`

Thanks for your help :)

```js
Downloading/unpacking yapf
  Downloading yapf-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118kB): 118kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: yapf
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yapftests'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/luis/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the same as root or with sudo

Comment: Haha nice I was thinking about it, thank you very much :)

Comment: Please set the Answer as Accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.